# SQL: How to count the number of unique days between date ranges that may overlap?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

I have a tricky problem. I have a table of social security contributions as below ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6a72/1))

```
    IdPersona   fecha_ingreso   fecha_egreso
5690180         01/01/1987      30/11/2012
5690180         01/01/2010      30/11/2012
5690180         11/06/2012      15/11/2012
5690180         12/04/2012      25/04/2012
5690180         16/03/2012      30/03/2012
5690180         18/06/2011      15/10/2011
5690180         20/12/2012      20/01/2013
5690180         21/11/2012      15/12/2012
```

Each row represents a job for the individual. The individual may have more than one job concurrently. I need to count how many days of contributions each individual made in a particular period, for example in the last year, The problem is that I must count only distinct days of contribution and not count the same day more than once for an individual. How can I achieve this?

---

Outline possible solution to count the number of days but not unique
1-Define date range, a time window for which count the contributions made by the people.
2-For each RespondentID I have to count how many different days with input window has during this period?

```
DECLARE @FchRef DATETIME

SET @FchRef ='2011-05-01'

--Fhc referencia de comienzo del programa a partir de cual calcular aportes
DECLARE @PeriRef SMALLINT

SET @PeriRef =24

--Periodo a partir de la Fch ref para contar aportes
DECLARE @FchCotDesde DATETIME

SET @FchCotDesde=Dateadd(MONTH, -24, @FchRef)

--Fch a partir de la cual calcular aportes
SELECT ut.documento                 'CI_UT',
       sum(DATEDIFF(DAY, CASE
                           WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME, act.fecha_ingreso, 103) < @FchCotDesde THEN @FchCotDesde
                           ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, act.fecha_ingreso, 103)
                         END, CASE
                                WHEN fecha_egreso = '' THEN @FchRef
                                ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, act.fecha_egreso, 103)
                              END)) 'DiasContados'
FROM   dbo.[UT2011_12] ut
       LEFT JOIN dbo.DatosPersonalesyDomicilios dat
         ON cast(cast(ut.documento AS DECIMAL(12, 0))AS VARCHAR) = dat.nro_documento
       LEFT JOIN dbo.Actividades act
         ON act.pers_identificador = dat.pers_identificador
            AND ( CONVERT(DATETIME, act.fecha_egreso, 103) = ''
                   OR CONVERT(DATETIME, act.fecha_egreso, 103) >= @FchCotDesde )
            -- La Fch de egreso es vacia ó con Fch posterior a fch ref
            AND CONVERT(DATETIME, act.fecha_ingreso, 103) <= @FchRef
--La Fch de inicio de act es anterior a la FchRef
WHERE  ut.UT_2011_Inscriptos = 1
        OR ut.UT_2012_Inscriptos = 1
GROUP  BY ut.documento
```

THE problem with this solution is that it works if the date range (ingress and egress) overlap.
It occurred to me as a solution to the problem: 1 - create a cursor that contains each of the people 2 - I create a loop that loops through day by day window period and if you throw one makes contributions and 0 but, for each of individuals. How will the solution I propose is extremely complex. Can you think of any better solution?

With this script you can create the table

```
        create table #aux(
        Idpersona int
        ,FechaIngreso datetime
        ,FechaEgreso  datetime
        ) 
    insert into #aux values(5690180,'1987/01/01','2012/11/30')
    insert into #aux values(5690180,'2010/01/01','2012/11/30')
    insert into #aux values(5690180,'2012/06/11','2012/11/15')
    insert into #aux values(5690180,'2012/04/12','2012/04/25')
    insert into #aux values(5690180,'2012/03/16','2012/03/30')
    insert into #aux values(5690180,'2011/06/18','2011/10/15')
    insert into #aux values(5690180,'2012/12/20','2013/01/20')
    insert into #aux values(5690180,'2012/11/21','2012/12/15')
    select * from #aux
```

I good way to see the problem is with one graphic

```
111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
|----A1----|
         |----A2----|
               |----A3----|

00000111111111111111110000001111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000
     |------B1-------|
                            |----------B2-----------|
```

Comment: +1 por la lengua castellano

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? (Oracle 11g, SQL Server 2008, etc)

Comment: @MartinSmith I agree with the question been closed as it is. For what it's worth, op was asking how can he count the distinct days on wich a person made "transactions". The catch is that the range between dates can overlap

Comment: This information applies to social security contributions. Each row represents a job for the individual. The individual may have more than one job. So I want to count how many days realize the individual contributions, for example in the last year mobile. The problem is that I have to count distinct days with contribution and not to sum the days.

Comment: I apologize for my english

Comment: Does `Ingress=1/1/2010, Egress=1/1/2010` count as zero(0) days or one(1) day?

Comment: Good question RBarryYoung, as 1day. This is one problem with my query, but with easy solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the simplest way would be to create an auxiliary table of dates.

```
CREATE TABLE Dates(D DATE PRIMARY KEY)

/*
Load dates between 1990-01-01 and 2049-12-31*/
INSERT INTO Dates
SELECT TOP (21915) DATEADD(DAY,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)), '19891231')
         AS N
   FROM master..spt_values v1,
        master..spt_values v2;
```

Then you can do

```
DECLARE @FchRef DATE = '20110501';
DECLARE @FchCotDesde DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, -24, @FchRef);

SELECT [IdPersona],
       COUNT(DISTINCT Dates.D) AS Contributions
FROM Contributions  
JOIN Dates ON Dates.D BETWEEN fecha_ingreso AND fecha_egreso
WHERE Dates.D BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -24, @FchRef) AND @FchRef
GROUP BY IdPersona
```

Comment: Thank you Martin, simple solution for a very complex problem.

Comment: There is a small detail with the fecha_egreso that can be NULL. But is very easy to handling

Comment: @EAguirre - Does that mean they are still working there? If so `ISNULL(fecha_egreso, GETDATE())` should do it.

Comment: Thank you Martin in this case should be ISNULL(fecha_egreso, @FchRef)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following. You first need to create a numbers function.

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[NumberTable] (@Min int, @Max int)
RETURNS @T TABLE (Number int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT @T VALUES (@Min)
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
INSERT @T
SELECT t.Number + (x.MaxNumber - @Min + 1)
FROM @T t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MaxNumber = MAX(Number) FROM @T) x --Current max
WHERE
t.Number <= @Max - (x.MaxNumber - @Min + 1)
END
RETURN
END
```

Then what I am doing is looping the jobs, getting the date from, and date to values and inserting all dates between.

```
 Declare @Dates table
(UserId int,
DayDate datetime
)

 create table #aux(id int identity(1,1),
        Idpersona int
        ,FechaIngreso datetime
        ,FechaEgreso  datetime
        ) 
    insert into #aux values(5690180,'1987/1/1','2012/11/30')
    insert into #aux values(5690180,'2010/1/1','2012/11/30')
    insert into #aux values(5690180,'2012/6/11','2012/11/15')
    insert into #aux values(5690180,'2012/4/12','2012/4/25')
    insert into #aux values(5690180,'2012/3/16','2012/3/30')
    insert into #aux values(5690180,'2011/6/18','2011/10/15')
    insert into #aux values(5690180,'2012/12/20','2013/1/20')
    insert into #aux values(5690180,'2012/11/21','2012/12/15')

    declare @counter int
    select @counter = 1 
 WHILE @counter <= (Select COUNT(*) from #aux)
    Begin

        declare @User int
        select @User = Idpersona from #aux where id = @counter

        declare @YearMonthDayFrom datetime
        declare @YearMonthDayTo datetime
        select @YearMonthDayFrom = FechaIngreso from #aux where id = @counter
        select @YearMonthDayTo= FechaEgreso from #aux where id = @counter

        Declare @DateDifference int
        select @DateDifference = datediff(day, @YearMonthDayFrom,  @YearMonthDayTo) 

        insert into @Dates 
        select @User,
         dateadd(day,number,  @YearMonthDayFrom) 
        from
        dbo.NumberTable(0,@DateDifference)

        select @counter = @counter + 1
    end

   select year(daydate) as PeriodGroup,
    UserId, 
    COUNT(distinct DayDate)
   from @Dates
   group by UserId,
   year(daydate)

   drop table #aux
```

Finally, I count the distinct days and in my example I am grouping by year.

Comment: I am having problems formatting the SQL. When I am using the <pre><code> closing tags under the drop table #aux, half of the code is disappearing. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't use `<pre><code>` I use the button on the toolbar to format as code. Looks fine to me now. Do you still see the issue? If so are you on an Ipad? It is a scrollable div. You need to use two fingers to drag it to see the rest of the code.

Comment: Looks fine now - I am on my PC however couldn't get it right for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: @EAguirre what is the problem that you're encountering?

Comment: No @EAguirre, if I understood you correctly, since the FechaIngreso is DateTime, when you insert '1987/1/1', it is equivalent to January 1st, 1987. When I see the results prior processing in the temporary table #aux, the values are correct.

Comment: @StephenBorg thank you for your reply. I apologize , I thought that there was a problem with the date-format with the insert